# how to set an If Then with a comboBox value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In Sheet1 I have a dropdown of countries configured as a ComboBox named COUNTRY and a TextBox called 'FEES'. The possible options are Spain, Portugal and Germany. If the option selected is Spain I want to write in cell
A2 from Sheet2 the value of FEES, If I select Germany, I want to write en cell A3 from Sheet2 the value of FEES and If the option is Portugal, I'll write in A4 from Sheet2 the value of FEES. I have tried with different options but no one works

```
If Sheet1.Country.Value = "Spain" Then
    Worksheet("Sheet2").Cells(2,1).Value = Sheet1.Fees.Value
End If

If Sheet1.Country.Value = "Germany" Then
    Worksheet("Sheet2").Cells(3,1).Value = Sheet1.Fees.Value
End If

If Sheet1.Country.Value = "Portugal" Then
    Worksheet("Sheet2").Cells(4,1).Value = Sheet1.Fees.Value
End If
```

Comment: What kind of combo box is the one your code uses? An ActiveX type or a Form type? Then, when do you like to work your code? Not when the combo value is changed? Do you want running it pressing a button?

Comment: It's an ActiveX but I don't know what's the different between the FormType. I'd like to work when I press a button that I've included

Comment: Are you sure that it is an ActiveX, since you do not know what a Form type is? And you name it as "dropdown"? What name did Excel initially used before you changed it in "COUNTRY"? "Drop down 1", or "Combobox1"?

Comment: Yes, it's ActiveX, Excel initially called it Combobox1

Comment: Then, you should use its click event to automatically fill the cell with the text box text... I will prepare a piece of code.

Comment: `Worksheet("Sheet2")`  should be `Worksheets("Sheet2")` with `s`

Answer (score 0):

Please, paste the next code in the sheet code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub COUNTRY_Change()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, cb As MSForms.ComboBox, txtF As MSForms.TextBox, no As Long
  
    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set cb = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("COUNTRY").Object
    Set txtF = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("fees").Object
    If cb.value = "Spain" Then
          no = 2
     ElseIf cb.value = "Portugal" Then
          no = 3
    ElseIf cb.value = "Germany" Then
         no = 4
    Else
        Debug.Print "Something else"
     End If
     sh.cells(no, 1).value = txtF.Text
End Sub
```

The sheet code module can be accessed with right click on the sheet name and choose "View Code"...